# Ruby streamline parsing process

Tags: ruby, string, performance, parsing

I have a pdf that is roughly 700 pgs. I am using this [gem](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader) to convert the pdf to a string like this:

```
require 'pdf/reader'

filename = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__)) + "/InvoiceS.pdf"
puts("PDF to Import/Convert to Text: #{filename}")
string = ""

PDF::Reader.open(filename) do |reader|
  reader.pages.each do |page|
    string << page.text
  end
end
```

I only want a certain range, so I take that range:

```
z = string.index('Page: 3 of 776')
y = string.index('Page: 74 of 776')
string1 = string[z..y]
```

Before any manipulation, the string is like this:

```
830 N BROADWAY ST LOUIS MO 63147

                                     1 314 381-3292           $43.19            $0.00            $0.00            $2.14           $45.33

                                     2 314 382-2158           $43.19            $0.00            $0.00            $2.14           $45.33


                                     3 314 385-9527           $43.19            $0.00            $0.00            $2.14           $45.33

                                     4 314 385-9537           $48.69            $0.00            $0.00            $2.57           $51.26

                                       Total                 $178.26            $0.00            $0.00            $8.99          $187.25


87 WESTERN AV UNIT 3A SOUTH PORTLAND ME 04106


                                     1 207 773-3801           $31.19            $0.00            $0.00            $4.47           $35.66

                                     2 207 773-3803           $36.69            $0.00            $0.00            $5.17           $41.86

                                     3 207 773-3804           $31.19            $0.00            $0.00            $4.47           $35.66

                                     4 207 773-8969           $35.81            $0.00            $0.00            $4.04           $39.85

                                     5 207 773-8970           $31.19            $0.00            $0.00            $4.47           $35.66


                                       Total                 $166.07            $0.00            $0.00           $22.62          $188.69


85 GERMANTOWN PKE PLYMOUTH PA 19462


                                     1 484 322-0448           $53.19            $0.00            $0.00            $7.96           $61.15

                                     2 484 322-0482           $53.19            $0.00            $0.00            $7.96           $61.15

                                     3 484 322-0483           $53.19            $0.00            $0.00            $7.96           $61.15

                                     4 484 322-0486           $47.19            $0.00            $0.00            $8.65           $55.84

                                     5 484 322-0489           $47.19            $0.00            $0.00            $8.65           $55.84

                                     6 610 275-3898           $53.19            $0.00            $0.00            $7.96           $61.15


                                       Total                 $307.14            $0.00            $0.00           $49.14          $356.28


855 GULF FRWY HOUSTON TX 77017

                                     1 723 910-0683           $46.69            $2.63            $0.00            $6.33           $55.65


                                     2 713 910-0697           $41.19            $0.00            $0.00            $5.35           $46.54

                                     3 520 297-3721             $0.00            $0.00          ($17.85)          ($1.29)         ($19.14)

                                     4 520 297-5004            $32.19            $0.00            $0.00            $3.65           $35.84

                                     5 520 297-5079            $32.19            $0.00            $0.00            $3.65           $35.84

                                     6 520 297-9889             $0.00            $0.00          ($15.87)          ($1.60)         ($17.47)

                                     7 520 297-9893             $0.00            $0.00          ($15.87)          ($1.60)         ($17.47)
                                                                                                                                   Page: 69 of 776
```

I clean up the string:

```
string2 = string1.squeeze(' ')
string3 = string2.gsub(/\n+/, "\n")
string4 = string3.gsub("\n ", "\n")
s = string4.gsub("Page:", "\nPage:")
```

New string:

```
830 N BROADWAY ST LOUIS MO 63147
1 314 381-3292 $43.19 $0.00 $0.00 $2.14 $45.33
2 314 382-2158 $43.19 $0.00 $0.00 $2.14 $45.33
3 314 385-9527 $43.19 $0.00 $0.00 $2.14 $45.33
4 314 385-9537 $48.69 $0.00 $0.00 $2.57 $51.26
Total $178.26 $0.00 $0.00 $8.99 $187.25
87 WESTERN AV UNIT 3A SOUTH PORTLAND ME 04106
1 207 773-3801 $31.19 $0.00 $0.00 $4.47 $35.66
2 207 773-3803 $36.69 $0.00 $0.00 $5.17 $41.86
3 207 773-3804 $31.19 $0.00 $0.00 $4.47 $35.66
4 207 773-8969 $35.81 $0.00 $0.00 $4.04 $39.85
5 207 773-8970 $31.19 $0.00 $0.00 $4.47 $35.66
Total $166.07 $0.00 $0.00 $22.62 $188.69
85 GERMANTOWN PKE PLYMOUTH PA 19462
1 484 322-0448 $53.19 $0.00 $0.00 $7.96 $61.15
2 484 322-0482 $53.19 $0.00 $0.00 $7.96 $61.15
3 484 322-0483 $53.19 $0.00 $0.00 $7.96 $61.15
4 484 322-0486 $47.19 $0.00 $0.00 $8.65 $55.84
5 484 322-0489 $47.19 $0.00 $0.00 $8.65 $55.84
6 610 275-3898 $53.19 $0.00 $0.00 $7.96 $61.15
Total $307.14 $0.00 $0.00 $49.14 $356.28
855 GULF FRWY HOUSTON TX 77017
1 723 910-0683 $46.69 $2.63 $0.00 $6.33 $55.65
2 713 910-0697 $41.19 $0.00 $0.00 $5.35 $46.54 
3 520 297-3721 $0.00 $0.00 ($17.85) ($1.29) ($19.14)
4 520 297-5004 $32.19 $0.00 $0.00 $3.65 $35.84
5 520 297-5079 $32.19 $0.00 $0.00 $3.65 $35.84
6 520 297-9889 $0.00 $0.00 ($15.87) ($1.60) ($17.47)
7 520 297-9893 $0.00 $0.00 ($15.87) ($1.60) ($17.47)
Page: 69 of 776
```

Now I want to parse through this, and create a CSV:

```
i = []
j = []
k = []
l = ""
f = false
g = false
num = 0
c = 0

start = Time.now

s.to_enum(:scan,/(\n)/i).map do
  i.push $`.size
end

finish = Time.now

puts("Indices Found!... in #{finish - start} seconds.")

start = Time.now
# THIS FOR LOOP PARSES THE DATA
for x in 0..i.size-1
  if s[i[x]+1]!~ /\D/
    if s[i[x]+2] == " " or s[i[x]+2]!~ /\D/
      if s[i[x]+2] == " " and s[i[x]+3] != " " then f = true; y = 3 elsif s[i[x]+2] != " " and s[i[x]+3] == " " then f = true; y = 4 end
    end

    if f
      if s[i[x]+y-1] == " " and s[i[x]+y] != " " and s[i[x]+y+1] != " " and s[i[x]+y+2] != " " and s[i[x]+y+3] == " " then g = true end
      f = false
    end

    if g
      j.push(s[i[x]+y..i[x+1]])
      m = j[num].tr('- (', '')
      k.push(m.split("$"))
      g = false
      num+=1
    end
  end
end

finish = Time.now; puts("Data Parsed!... in #{finish - start} seconds.")

# THIS FOR LOOP ACCOUNTS FOR NEGATIVE VALUES WHICH ARE IN (PARENTHESES) IN THE TEXT
for x in 0...k.size
  for y in 0...k[x].size
    if k[x][y].to_s.include? ")"
      m = k[x][y].tr(')','')
      m.prepend('-')
      k[x][y] = m
      l << k[x][y]
      if y != 5 then l << "," end
    else
      l << k[x][y]
      if y != 5 then l << "," end
    end
  end
end



# puts(l) # Prints the final csv in the terminal
puts("Extracted #{6*num} cells of data from a #{s.length} character file...)
```

The final string is this:

```
3143813292,43.19,0.00,0.00,2.14,45.33
3143822158,43.19,0.00,0.00,2.14,45.33
3143859527,43.19,0.00,0.00,2.14,45.33
3143859537,48.69,0.00,0.00,2.57,51.26
2077733801,31.19,0.00,0.00,4.47,35.66
2077733803,36.69,0.00,0.00,5.17,41.86
2077733804,31.19,0.00,0.00,4.47,35.66
2077738969,35.81,0.00,0.00,4.04,39.85
2077738970,31.19,0.00,0.00,4.47,35.66
4843220448,53.19,0.00,0.00,7.96,61.15
4843220482,53.19,0.00,0.00,7.96,61.15
4843220483,53.19,0.00,0.00,7.96,61.15
4843220486,47.19,0.00,0.00,8.65,55.84
4843220489,47.19,0.00,0.00,8.65,55.84
6102753898,53.19,0.00,0.00,7.96,61.15
7239100683,46.69,2.63,0.00,6.33,55.65
7139100697,41.19,0.00,0.00,5.35,46.54
5202973721,0.00,0.00,-17.85,-1.29,-19.14
5202975004,32.19,0.00,0.00,3.65,35.84
5202975079,32.19,0.00,0.00,3.65,35.84
5202979889,0.00,0.00,-15.87,-1.60,-17.47
5202979893,0.00,0.00,-15.87,-1.60,-17.47
```

Is there a way to streamline this?

Keep in mind the string outputs are much larger then what I have pasted here.

Also I am looking into how to write a csv file using the final string to the same folder where I read the pdf.

Please point out anything that is bad practice as I am new to Ruby and want to learn.

Comment: What would be your input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain all of these , since each will return the value after the operation was performed:

```
s = string[z..y].squeeze(' ').gsub(/\n+/, "\n").gsub("\n ", "\n").gsub("Page:", "\nPage:")
```

You can probably do some minor optimisations.
Your original two `gsub` mean:

1. Replace all multi new-lines with one new-line.
2. Replace all new-line with a space after it

You can change it to:

```
gsub(/\n+\s*/,"\n")
```

Meaning , replace all newlines (1 or more occurrences) and any white space found after them with one newline.

Or

```
gsub(/\n+/,"\n").gsub(/^\s*|\s*$/,'')
```

Meaning , replace all newline (1 or more occurrences)  with one newline.
Remove all whitespace at the beginning and end of the lines.

Post edit answer:

This is a little more compact , from eyeballing the results they look the same as yours:

```
s = string.squeeze(' ').gsub(/\n+\s*/,"\n").gsub("Page:", "\nPage:")


csv = []
s.split("\n").each do |line|
  tmp = line.chomp.split.map { |i|  i.gsub(/^\(/,'-').gsub(/\)/,'').gsub('$','') }
  next unless tmp.size == 8
  csv << "#{tmp[1..2].join.gsub('-','')},#{tmp[3..-1].join(',')}"
end
puts csv.join("\n")
```

Results:

```
3143813292,43.19,0.00,0.00,2.14,45.33
3143822158,43.19,0.00,0.00,2.14,45.33
3143859527,43.19,0.00,0.00,2.14,45.33
3143859537,48.69,0.00,0.00,2.57,51.26
2077733801,31.19,0.00,0.00,4.47,35.66
2077733803,36.69,0.00,0.00,5.17,41.86
2077733804,31.19,0.00,0.00,4.47,35.66
2077738969,35.81,0.00,0.00,4.04,39.85
2077738970,31.19,0.00,0.00,4.47,35.66
4843220448,53.19,0.00,0.00,7.96,61.15
4843220482,53.19,0.00,0.00,7.96,61.15
4843220483,53.19,0.00,0.00,7.96,61.15
4843220486,47.19,0.00,0.00,8.65,55.84
4843220489,47.19,0.00,0.00,8.65,55.84
6102753898,53.19,0.00,0.00,7.96,61.15
7239100683,46.69,2.63,0.00,6.33,55.65
7139100697,41.19,0.00,0.00,5.35,46.54
5202973721,0.00,0.00,-17.85,-1.29,-19.14
5202975004,32.19,0.00,0.00,3.65,35.84
5202975079,32.19,0.00,0.00,3.65,35.84
5202979889,0.00,0.00,-15.87,-1.60,-17.47
5202979893,0.00,0.00,-15.87,-1.60,-17.47
```

Comment: I have updated my question, before I mark this as the answer, do you want to provide any other feedback?

Comment: @Lyres check now

Comment: almost there... could you explain what happens in that loop? also an address like this "1 PILLSBURY ST CONCORD NH 03301" will become, "PILLSBURYST,SUIT,100,CONCORD,NH,03301". would want to skip over this

Comment: I detected assesses by tmp.size , if the real case has more complex cases you can add them to the ‘next’ condition

Comment: could you explain what these two lines do "s.split("\n").each do |line|
  tmp = line.chomp.split.map { |i|  i.gsub(/^\(/,'-').gsub(/\)/,'').gsub('$','') }" also how woud I add to the next condition I tried "next unless tmp.size == 8 or tmp[0] != /\D/"

Comment: `s` is your string with the each line. `split("\n")` turns it into an array by splitting it on each newline. `line.chomp.split` removes the newline and split the line into an array by default by whitespace. `map` runs the multiple `gsub` commands on each resulting array cells to format them according to your needs.

Comment: Try to avoid multiple logical conditions in `unless` since it's basically De Morgan law and can be confusing. Try `next if ( tmp.size != 8 && !tmp[0].match(/\d/) )` . I personally prefer using `match` and I think I saw in the past some issues with multiple logical conditions in an inline `if` so I always put parenthesis just to be on the safe side (probably not needed)

Comment: Thank you so much for this insight. I am new to ruby and just seeing how you condensed all the logic into a few lines of code baffles me. This language is super interesting...

Comment: Although I’m a huge Ruby lover, my code is smaller due to a different reason. You went the explicit way, iterating over characters etc. while I used regex and the input format to squeeze it into a couple of logical , human readable commands. I parse text for years now in various languages so I’m used to finding these rules/patterns in formats. Anyway, Ruby is hands down my favorite and most elegant language to date.

Comment: I tried to use your 'next if ( tmp.size != 8 && !tmp[0].match(/\d/) )' but got the error 'undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)'

Comment: This is probably since tmp[0] is nil. Try adding puts “#{tmp.inspect}” before the if to see when/why it fails.

Comment: when you do something like this |line| are you creating a variable?

Comment: Yes, please check how Ruby iterative work. There very simple tutorials available.

Comment: Thanks! Okay one last question, why put a ! in front of !tmp[0].match(/\d/)

Comment: ! Is to revert the logical condition. You can use tmp[0].match(/\d/).nil? If you prefer not negating logical conditions.

Comment: Cool thanks! and lets say i want any 3 digit number in a regex is there a better way then this /[0-9][0-9][0-9]/. I want to include 000, 001...

Answer (score 2):

```
string[z..y].
  squeeze(' ').
  gsub(/\n+/, "\n").
  gsub("\n ", "\n").
  gsub("Page:", "\nPage:")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer this question has no long-term value, neither does the answer. Feel free to provide whatever you consider valuable.

Comment: @mudasobwa i have update my question hopefully this helps